# How to add information to openstreetmap data?

Tags: openstreetmap

I would like to add information to openstreetmap (routes,POI) but in a local version not to the version that is deployed on the web. So how can I do that ?

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/is-there-a-way-to-locally-add-links-to-an-osm-data-set?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do wish to use them :
If you just want the data: You can download osm-data in a number of formats (shp, glm, file geodatabase) from http://market.weogeo.com/ . You edit those. 
QGIS also has a plugin that allows you to edit OSM-data.
Merkaartor ( http://merkaartor.be ) is dedicated desktop app that allows you to edit osm-data locally and export it if you want.
With maperitive.net  ( http://maperitive.net ) you can load, modify, export osm-data to svg of images.